# Rails - HowTo - Handle Users w/o Images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I just installed paper_clip to allow user's to upload a profile pic which can be displayed easily with:

```
<%= image_tag @user.profile_pic.url %>
```

What I'm curious about now is how to handle user's that don't have a profile_pic uploaded.. How to show a standard site user image (generic)

Should I make a helper?

something like `showProfilePic(@user, size)`

And then use that helper to show the right size image, either the user's uploaded photo or a generic site profile pic?

thanks. Any existing helpers out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `default_url` and `default_style` options to set this.  The default default_url is /:attachment/:style/missing.png, so you could drop in missing.png for each style and have that be your generic profile pic.  If you want to customize, though...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :profile_pic, 
    :default_style => :thumbnail,
    :default_url => '/path/to/:style_default.jpg'
end
```

Comment: this  worked very well. What about if I want to show a user's LARGE style, which isn't the default? How do I do <%= image_tag @user.profile_pic.url %>, but show LARGE, and if one doesn't exist, how to show a default per style?